# Run jquery function after another function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a custom Jquery function after another custom function completes
I use timer to func2. It is not correctly solution.
How can I write it؟

```js
function fun1() {
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function(){
     if($(this).find('ul').length){
        $(this).addClass('remove');}
     $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.remove > a').replaceWith(function(){
         return $('<span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">'+$(this).html()+'</span>' );
        });
    });
};

setTimeout(
    function fun2() {
        $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').removeClass('additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow');
        $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').addClass('static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode'); 
        //do something special
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You can call `func2` at the end of `func1` like `function fun1(){...... func1() }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Call fun2() inside fun1()

like this

```
function fun2() {
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').removeClass('additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow');
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').addClass('static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode'); 
    //do something special
}

function fun1() {
$('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('ul').length){
    $(this).addClass('remove');}
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.remove > a').replaceWith(function(){
        return $('<span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">'+$(this).html()+'</span>' );
    });
});

fun2() ;//Call function 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you define function 2 and call it inside function 1 at it's end?

```
function fun1() {
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('ul').length){
        $(this).addClass('remove');}
        $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.remove > a').replaceWith(function(){
            return $('<span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">'+$(this).html()+'</span>' );
        });
    });
   //calling function 2 here
   fun2();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call the fun2 at the end of the fun1 ?

```js
function fun2() {
$('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').removeClass('additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow');
$('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.father > span').addClass('static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode');
//do something special
}


function fun1() {

$('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length) {
        $(this).addClass('remove');
    }
    $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.remove > a').replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    });
});
  
   fun2();//Call the fun2
}
```